# Is it possible to sync Adium and Pidgin accounts settings?

Tags: pidgin, adium

I use Pidgin at my netbook (Windows) and work (again Windows) and sync their accounts settings using Dropbox (by syncing their .purple folder as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15053/sync-your-pidgin-profile-across-multiple-pcs-with-dropbox/)). I want to have Adium on my Mac do the same.
I created a symbolic link from "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0/Users/Default/libpurple" to my ".purple" folder in DropBox, but alas, it doesn't work.

Is it possible? They are both based on libpurple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libpurple, from my understanding, is used to deal with the protocols themselves and not necessarily the settings.  I did a bit of searching around and there was talk at one time of trying to sync them up, but nothing became of it.  So as far as settings go, I think you're stuck with having two separate things.